# How does enable_if help select specializations of a class template?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, template-specialization, enable-if, class-template

I have a basic grasp of SFINAE, and I think I understand many of the examples of how `std::enable_if` exploits it to select function template specializations, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how it works for class templates.

The following example is from [cppreference.com's explanation of `std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```cpp
template<class T, class Enable = void>
class A {}; // primary template

template<class T>
class A<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type> {
}; // specialization for floating point types
```

I'm having trouble understanding how using `std::enable_if` in this way helps select the specialization.  (I don't doubt that it does.)

When the compiler sees a declaration like `A<float> specialized;`, it will see two possible template instantiations that fit:

1. The "primary template" `A<T, Enable>` where `T` is the type `float` and Enable is the type `void` (because of the default value).
2. The specialization `A<T, void>` where `T` is the type `float` and `void` is the result of the expression with the `enable_if`.

Aren't those ambiguous?  Both effectively result in `A<T, void>`, so why is the specialization chosen?

In a different case, like `A<int> primary;`, the options to the compiler seem to be:

1. The primary, `A<T, Enable>`, where `T` is the type `int` and `Enable` is the type `void`.
2. The specialization, `A<T, ?>`, where `T` is the type `int` and the `?` represents where I'm completely lost.  In this case, the `enable_if` condition is false, so it doesn't define `type`, which leaves you with `A<int, typename >`.  Isn't that a syntax error?  Even in the face of SFINAE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the reference on [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) of class templates:

> When a class or variable (since C++14) template is instantiated, and there are partial specializations available, the compiler has to decide if the primary template is going to be used or one of its partial specializations.
>
> > If only one specialization matches the template arguments, that specialization is used

In this case, if the 2nd argument of the specialization is well-formed, it is chosen, *precisely because* it is a specialization, and not the primary template.

In case the 2nd template argument is *not* well-formed, then [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) kicks in. In particular:

> When substituting the explicitly specified or deduced type for the template parameter fails, the specialization is discarded from the overload set *instead of causing a compile error*.

and

> The following type errors are SFINAE errors:
>
> > attempting to use a member of a type, where
> >     the type does not contain the specified member

How this is done, i.e. how exactly the compiler discards the specialization, instead of giving an error, is not specified; the compiler is just required to do the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

> Aren't those ambiguous? Both effectively result in `A<T, void>`, so why is the specialization chosen?

No, the specialization is *more specialized* than the primary template, because it requires the second parameter to be `void` (assuming the `enable_if` condition is true), while the primary template doesn't restrict it.

> The specialization, `A<T, ?>`, where `T` is the type `int` and the `?` represents where I'm completely lost. In this case, the `enable_if` condition is false, so it doesn't define type, which leaves you with `A<int, typename >`. Isn't that a syntax error? Even in the face of SFINAE?

Exactly, the second argument in the specialization turns out invalid. But this is a "soft" error, which is detected by SFINAE and makes the compiler discard the specialization. (I don't think a compiler would textually replace `enable_if_t<...>::type` with an empty string and then analyze `A<int, typename >`; more likely it would discard the specialization as soon as it notices the lack of `::type` in `enable_if`.)

Comment: Your last sentence, the one in parentheses, was key to getting past my mental block.  Thanks!